# Pronunciation of numbers with respect to years

Tags: grammar-choice, pronunciation, calendarium, numerals

I understand that when dates are written, the years are expressed in Roman numerals (e.g.: 2019 is written MMXIX), but it has been years since I heard the numbers actually pronounced.

How were the numbers of the years expressed verbally? Were they cardinal, ordinal, or otherwise? And with that in what case were they: nominative or ablative?

AD 2019 is pronounced *anno domini...* (what)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The numbers are ordinals in the singular masculine ablative.
They modify the word *anno*, having its form.
In Latin you say literally "on the 2019th year", which is *anno bis millesimo undevicesimo*.
You can of course add *Domini* or *ante Christum natum* or some such phrase if you want, but it is often clear enough in context — just like in English.

Comment: So 2000th is *bis millesimo* rather than something like *duo millesimo*? Could you please explain how that works?

Comment: @MediaMatellaLucretiaFlores That's how Latin ordinals work. I recommend asking a separate question about that actually, so that the matter gets properly explored. The 2 in 2000 behaves differently with cardinals and ordinals, and this is not unique to Latin.